# "walk" through view after search

Tags: xpages

I have a view with a computed search.
I would like to go through the searched view ,line by line like getFirstEntry(), do some things and then getNextEntry() , and so on...
I tried :

```
var entryCount = view1.getEntryCount();
var viewControl = getComponent( 'viewPanel1' );
var rowCount = viewControl.getRowCount();
// If search is active -> rowcount, else entrycount
var entries = viewControl.getDataSource().getSearch();
var count = ( viewControl.getDataSource().getSearch() ) ? rowCount :entryCount;
// next line is the problem 
var currentEntry = entries.getFirstEntry();
country = currentEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(0);
```

This gives an error :

> Unknown member 'getFirstEntry' in Java class 'java.lang.String'

Comment: *getSearch()* returns a String: The search formula of your view. Not a viewEntryCollection.

Comment: is it possible to get a viewEntryCollection of a view after a search ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the view with this line:

```
viewControl.getDataSource().getView()
```

**Edit - more complete snippet**

```
var viewControl = getComponent( 'viewPanel1' );
var view = viewControl.getDataModel().getDominoViewData().getDataObject();
var entries = view.getAllEntries();
var entry = entries.getFirstEntry();
while( entry ){
    // your code
    entry = entries.getNextEntry();
}
```

Comment: Euh, sorry Tommy , but I don't understand how to change the above code with your suggestion. Where do I put the line ? I don't need the complete view. Only the result after the search.

Comment: *var entries = viewControl.getDataSource().getView().getAllEntries()* returns a *viewEntryCollection* with the search result.

Comment: Sven, with this line I get all the entries from the complete view.Not the result after the search. Strange since viewControl.getRowCount(); gives the correct number of rows after the search ...

Comment: Tommy , when I put var entries = viewControl.getDataSource().getView(); I'm getting an error: Error calling method 'getFirstEntry()' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.View

Comment: @Marc: Works for me like a charm. Please provide more infos/source code.

Comment: @Marc: If you read Sven's answer.. _var entries = viewControl.getDataSource().getView().getAllEntries();_ Then you can use the resulting **ViewEntryCollection** to walk the view. E.g. _var entry = entries.getFirstEntry();_

Comment: @Tommy: in your edited code I added behind // your code : position = entry.getColumnValues().elementAt(11); and then I copy the value of position to a scoped variable and I see that he is running through the complete view instead of the view limited to the searched items. The search has been done in the viewPanel under Data and then Search this view.

Comment: I did a little test/updated the code with **viewControl.getDataModel().getDominoViewData().getDataObject()**. I managed to crash the server when I tested this. I'm not sure if this was due to a lot of entries, or something else, so use with care :)